# Grails migration issues. DBM-UPDATE include not recursing, fails silently

Tags: grails, dbmigrate, changelog

This is part of an ongoing project... splitting out domain objects so they can be consumed by multiple applications.  The database migration files for the domain objects live with the plugin... but we want the apps to be able to reference them during a dbm-update.

I can get the application to recognize the plugin changelog, but after that, the changelog does not perform includes and process them as I expect.

Using GrailsPluginUtils I am able to get the path of the plugin and the plugin changelog, with which I do an include file.  If I put the changeSet right in that file I am good, it runs.  If I move it to a separate file in the same folder, or in a sub-folder, and reference it via "./someFile.groovy" it seems to FIND it but does not process it.  I say it seems to find it because if I do NOT use a relative file path, the migration process throws an error saying it cannot find the file e.g., "someFile.groovy"...

I have workarounds but they are not acceptable because we want to control the order of how the DB migrations occur by using sub-directors with a _changelog.groovy that then includes the actual transformations (changeSets).  But they are not being "include"ed.

If I use includeAll, it will grab any and all scripts in that one folder, but again, does not process any other includes referenced therein.  I can write a script to scan the folders recursively but again, that requires a lot of coding to parse the _changelogs and grab the appropriate inclusion order, etc.

I really just want "include file:" to work as it does in a given application for its own changelog files.

Has anyone else done this?  Am I missing something terribly obvious?

In the app...

```
databaseChangeLog {
...
    include file: "${GrailsPluginUtils.pluginInfos.find { it.name == 'my-plugin' }.pluginDir}/grails-app/migrations/my_plugin_changes"
}
```

... in the plugin...

```
databaseChangeLog {
    include file: "./someChangeLogChangeSet.groovy"
}
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

We had also tried adding changelog files to the plugin where our domains live but were unable to access it from the main app. However, if you want to access your files from other location then you could specify this property in your config file and give the folder name here Or even copy all the migrations to the appropriate location to the main app.

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.changelogLocation = 'migrations'
```

If you do find a actual solution to this, please post it.

Comment: If I do I will jump for joy and share it with the world.  My current experiment is to write a chunk of code in the master changelog that basically does the parsing / includes that the migration plugin / liquibase is supposed to do for you.  Hate it tho'.